# Convert Zulu time zone to a specific format with javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date data with Zulu time zone, for example:

```
2017-10-13T00:00:00Z
```

Is there any suggestion how to convert this kind of time to the Long Date format with Javascript- e.g: `Oct 13 2017`? What is the correct?

**[EDIT]**

For a more in-depth view of dates and times in JavaScript, you can read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Why downvoted? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Have you tried something? Where is your code?

Comment: @Justinas I'm asking a way how to do that.

Comment: You should first try searching your self, like type in google `JS convert date format`

Comment: @Justinas Thanks, because it's an old system. I confused how to convert this kind of date, so I'm finding a guide.

Comment: @Justinas Thanks! ah. It's not difficult than I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wan't to use `toLocaleDateString`

```js
var result = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }).replace(',', '');
console.log(result);
```

For more informations see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)

Comment: Thank for your input, I will check and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```
var d = new Date('2017-10-13T00:00:00Z');
var monthArray = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
var dateFormatted = monthArray[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + d.getDate() + ' ' + d.getFullYear();
```

`dateFormatted` is the variable that could then be output with the date in the required format.